# Cant get forEach in Meteor to work

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-helper

I have been trying to figure out how to get forEach loop to work in Meteor for a few days. I have a `QuestionList` collection that has two arrays (`usersTrue` `usersFalse`) for the people that guess on the question. I want to go through both arrays and change the users score when I answer the question. I think I am really close but I am calling one of the two collections incorrectly.

Two collections `QuestionList` that links to the question collection and `UserList` that connects to `Meteor.users`

I have publications

```
Meteor.publish('activeQuestions', function(){
return QuestionList.find({ });
});

Meteor.publish('userNotAnswered', function(){
var currentUserId = this.userId;
return QuestionList.find({active: true, usersTrue: {$nin: [currentUser]}, 
    usersFalse: {$nin: [currentUser]}});
});

Meteor.publish('userAnswer', function(){
var currentUserId = this.userId;
return UserList.find({_id: currentUserId});
});
```

I have templates for the admin side when I answer the question. It calls the `modifyQuestionStatus` method with a few parameters.

```
Template.activeQuestionList.events({
'click [data-action=questionTrue]': function() {

    // Select the id of the yes button that is clicked
    var questionId = this._id;
    Session.set('answered', questionId);

    // Get the session
    var answered = Session.get('answered');

    // Update the database without losing any data
    Meteor.call('modifyQuestionStatus', answered, true);

},
'click [data-action=questionTrue]': function() {
    // Select the id of the yes button that is clicked
    var questionId = this._id;
    Session.set('answered', questionId);

    // Get the session
    var answered = Session.get('answered');

    // Update the database without losing any data
    Meteor.call('modifyQuestionStatus', answered, false);
}

});
```

Finally I have the method

```
    'modifyQuestionStatus' : function(questionId, answer){
    QuestionList.update(questionId, {$set: {active: false, answer: answer}});
    var base = QuestionList.find({_id: questionId});
    if (answer === true) {
        base.usersTrue.forEach(function (user) {
            user.update(secret, {$set: {coins: 100}} );
        });
        base.usersFalse.forEach(function (user) {
            user.update(secret, {$set: {coins: -100}} );
        });
    } else {
        usersFalse.forEach(function (user) {
            UserList.update(secret, {$set: {coins: 100}} );
        });
        usersTrue.forEach(function (user) {
            UserList.update(secret, {$set: {coins: -100}} );
        });
    }
},
```

secret is an array that the coins are stored in.

I know the code is not perfect but I want to get the code working before I clean it up. I think I put enough info. I am new to programming so let me know if I am missing anything that helps answer the question.

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Comment: Exception while invoking method 'modifyQuestionStatus' TypeError: Cannot call method 'forEach' of undefined.

Comment: Looks like `userTrue` or `userFalse` is `undefined`. Are you setting those somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

base is a cursor you probably need fetch() here:

```
var base = QuestionList.find({_id: questionId}).fetch();
```

or even findOne() :

```
var base = QuestionList.findOne({_id: questionId});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'modifyQuestionStatus' : function(questionId, answer){
    QuestionList.update(questionId, {$set: {active: false, answer: answer}});

    var usersTrue = _.pluck( QuestionList.find({"_id": questionId}).fetch(), 'usersTrue' );
    var usersFalse = _.pluck( QuestionList.find({"_id": questionId}).fetch(), 'usersFalse' );
    if (answer === true) {
        usersTrue.forEach(function (user) {
            console.log("These users get 100 coins " + user);
            Session.set('userData', user);
            var userData = Session.get('userData');
            Meteor.users.update(userData, {$inc: { "coins.$.coins": 100}} );
        });
        usersFalse.forEach(function (user) {
            console.log("These users lose 100 coins " + user);
            Meteor.users.update({ _id: user}, {$inc: { "coins.$.coins": -100}} );
        });
    } else {
        usersFalse.forEach(function (user) {
            console.log("These users get 100 coins " + user);
            UserList.update({ _id: user}, {$inc: { "coins.coins": 100}} );
        });
        usersTrue.forEach(function (user) {
            console.log("These users lose 100 coins " + user);
            UserList.update({ _id: user}, {$inc: { "coins.coins": -100}} );
        });
    }
},
```

Used fetch and declared usersTrue and usersFalse as variables. The code works but is not updating the coins document.